# (Flutter) HTTPClient Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

Tags: flutter, http, httpclient, uri, host

Currently working on a little app that allows users to view a database stored on Heroku, however I am running into the aforementioned issue when using the database's URL: ".herokuapp.com/api/".

```
var client = createHttpClient();
var response = await client.read('<example>.herokuapp.com/api/<data>');
List data = JSON.decode(response);
```

Heroku doesn't seem to use HTTP(S) nor www, the latter of which I believe to be the issue.

Does anyone know how I can bypass or resolve this issue?

Comment: what happens if you use the browser or curl or wget to access the url?

Comment: I'm not sure what `wget` or `curl` is, but a browser works fine.

Comment: `wget` and `curl` are command line tools to make HTTP requests. What does the URL look like in the browsers devtools where the browser logs network requests?

Comment: Where exactly can I find it there, as I tried looking previously to no avail?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no and to be honest so much has happened in the last few months I can't even remember what this was about :/

Comment: Uri(path: urlPathWithHttp);

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I know this is an old problem but I just stumbled into this problem and fixed it by adding an **`"http://"`** before the URL.

Answer (score 15):

One of the problem is not having "http://" before your API URL;

**SOLUTION**
Add "http://" before your API URL
*example*
API_URL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city%20name}&appid={your%20api%20key}"

By adding "http://" it becomes
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city%20name}&appid={your%20api%20key}"

Answer (score 8):

If you still get this issue in latest versions of flutter, try to check the following things.

Previously **uri** was in **String** type. Now its in **Uri** type for the http requests.

If we try to use the url as

```
String urlPath = '<example>.herokuapp.com/api/<data>';
client.read(Uri(path: urlPath));
```

We will get the exception as **No host specified in URI**

This can be solved by using **parse** method in **Uri** class

```
client.read(Uri.parse(urlPath));
```

It solves the issue.

Comment: nice! worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: imageFile != null
          ? FileImage(imageFile)
          : imgUrl.isNotEmpty
              ? NetworkImage(imgUrl)
              : null,),
```

Answer (score 2):

**This has worked for me**

```
CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl:  'https://example.com/'+item['image'],),
```

Comment: How is this different from the earlier answers that not only show the same solution but also explain it, and also more directly relate to the original question?

Answer (score 1):

You should always specify a Default Value of the Image Path if you are displaying the image on the same page try adding this to your widget:

```
  child: Image.network(
     valueOrDefault<String>(                                              
      listViewDocumentsRecord.docImageUrl,                                             
      'https://picsum.photos/seed/513/600',
       ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `http://` before your url

From :

```
 192.168.2.101/test/login
```

To :

```
 http://192.168.2.101/test/login
```

Answer (score 0):

[Problem may occur if you are accessing the imageUrl from Api. It takes sometime to load and if you leave the Url space empty in null situation this problem may arise.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmp16.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to breakdown the URL as per the uri sytax to the following:

For normal non-secured URLs:

```
final httpUri = Uri(
    scheme: 'http',
    host: 'dart.dev',
    path: 'guides/libraries/library-tour',
    fragment: 'numbers');
print(httpUri); // http://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#numbers
```

---

For secured URLs:

```
final httpsUri = Uri(
    scheme: 'https',
    host: 'dart.dev',
    path: 'guides/libraries/library-tour',
    fragment: 'numbers');
print(httpsUri); // https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#numbers
```

---

For email URLs use the following:

```
final mailtoUri = Uri(
    scheme: 'mailto',
    path: 'John.Doe@example.com',
    queryParameters: {'subject': 'Example'});
print(mailtoUri); // mailto:John.Doe@example.com?subject=Example
```